# MVVM Cross Nesting of fragments gives ViewModel Property of Fragment as NULL

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Currently I am using MVVM Cross 4.1.4 in my android Project. I didn't had much time to explore the samples hence I had/am trying to learn
and implement the MVVM Cross framework in my android enterprise application.
I have two huge issues which are making me sleepless and I am sure someone might right there will be facing the same issue.

In my app design I have made a single activity and all the other screens are just fragments which are not exactly controlled by actvity.
The activity just calls `ShowViewModel<SomeViewModel>` on click of something nothing fancy.

In a particular screen which is itself a fragment I have a view pager which are fragments, so its a nesting of fragments( 3rd fragment in hierarchy) What I noticed is that the ViewModel Property which MvxFragment has is coming null in the 3rd level nesting.
    Please see the code

```cs
public class MainActivity : MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity<MainViewModel>
{
}

public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
   ShowViewModel<FirstViewModel>();
}

public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}

[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
public class FirstFragment : MvxFragment<FirstViewModel>
{
}

public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}

[MvxFragment(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
[MvxFragment(typeof(FirstViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
public class SecondFragment: MvxFragment<SecondViewModel>
{
}
```

- The problem is inside the first fragment I have to manage a work flow of three fragments which can then have more fragments inside them i.e. 4 level fragments.
- The problem is inside the SecondFragment which is hosted by FirstFragment's viewpager adapter, the ViewModel property is coming null, WHY is that?

Since in FirstFragment ViewModel property doesn't come null and I can easily hit my PCL to get the data.
I know I am doing something wrong any help will be much appreciated. I have many problems to solve in my MVVM android project.

Comment: Datacontext for your ViewPager will not be set automatically by MvvmCross. How to you fill your ViewPager with the required fragments ?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there any way to bump this? I can't find anything anywhere.